# custom specifier in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to format the numeric value in java script /jquery like that doing in C#. please refer below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=VS.90%29.aspx#SpecifierD

what are the formats currently we can do in javascript (currency, percentange,numeric).

i know that jquery.globalize script will do some formats like ($,%) i want to know what are the formats we can perform or implement in javascript.

is there any in build function for format the date time like format in C#

(dd/mm/yy)

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [this](https://code.google.com/p/javascript-number-formatter/) ([DEMO](http://www.integraxor.com/developer/codes/js-formatter/format-sample.htm)) ?

Comment: whether it is a custom plugin ?

Comment: it is a custom plugin, jQuery is a custom plugin :)

Comment: I'm a fan of [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for date formatting in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I am not a great fan of the "plugins with jam" and "plugins with ketchup" approach to solving problems. As a general rule when you find yourself thinking "How can I do X in JavaScript like I do it in C# or PHP" it is well worth checking out [PHP JS](http://phpjs.org/).  In the present instance I suspect the [sprintf](http://phpjs.org/functions/sprintf/) function will do the trick.

Another useful function is this

```
String.prototype.format = function (args)
{
 var newStr = this;
 for (var key in args){newStr = newStr.replace('{' + key + '}', args[key]);}
 return newStr;
}

//for example
console.log("You owe me ${aa}".format({aa:100}));
```

The string prototype extension is not my own work - I found it somewhere.  Maybe here on SO, I cannot remember.